# Show me an Injection Attack for this Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, sql-injection

I notice that many people have said it's possible to create an injection attack, but my understanding is that is if someone is creating a query from a string, not parameters. In order to test the statement that Stored Procedures do not protect you against Injection Attacks, I am putting this example up in the hopes someone can show me a vulnerability if there is one.

Please note that I have built the code this way to easily insert a function that calls a procedure and embed it in a SELECT query. That means I cannot create a Prepared Statement. Ideally I'd like to keep my setup this way, as it is dynamic and quick, but if someone can create an injection attack that works, obviously that is not going to happen.

```
DELIMITER $$

#This procedure searches for an object by a unique name in the table.
#If it is not found, it inserts. Either way, the ID of the object
#is returned.

CREATE PROCEDURE `id_insert_or_find` (in _value char(200), out _id bigint(20))
BEGIN
    SET @_value = _value;
    SET @id = NULL;
    SELECT id INTO _id FROM `table` WHERE name=_value;

    IF _id IS NULL THEN
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO `table` (`name`) VALUE (_value);
            SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO _id;
        END;
    END IF;
END$$

CREATE FUNCTION `get_id` (_object_name char(200)) RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    SET @id = NULL;
    call `id_insert_or_find`(_object_name,@id);

    return @id;
END$$
```

### The PHP Code

The PHP code I use here is:

(*note, Boann has pointed out the folly of this code, below. I am not editing it for the sake of honoring the answer, but it will certainly not be a straight query in the code. It will be updated using ->prepare, etc. I still welcome any additional comments if new vulnerabilities are spotted.*)

```
function add_relationship($table_name,$table_name_child) {
    #This table updates a separate table which has 
    #parent/child relationships listed.
    $db->query("INSERT INTO table_relationships (`table_id`,`tableChild_id`) VALUES (get_id('{$table_name}'),get_id('{$table_name_child}')");
}
```

The end result is

```
table `table`
id      name
1       oak
2       mahogany
```

Now if I wanted to make oak the child of mahogany, I could use

```
add_relationship("mahogany","oak");
```

And if I wanted to make plastic the child of oak, I could use

```
add_relationship("oak","plastic");
```

Hopefully that helps give some framework and context.

Comment: It's not possible for there to be an injection attack in this code, because that's something that's only possible when building a query from a string. Either the people who said it was vulnerable were idiots or they were referring to the PHP/Java/etc code that calls this procedure.

Comment: Thanks Boann. That's what I was looking for. I will wait on other answers but that was my suspicion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly speaking, that query should be written to escape the table names:

```
$db->query("INSERT INTO table_relationships (`table_id`,`tableChild_id`) " .
    "VALUES (get_id(" . $db->quote($table_name) + ")," .
    "get_id(" . $db->quote($table_name_child) . "))");
```

Otherwise, it would break out of the quotes if one of the parameters contained a single quote. If you only ever call that function using literal strings in code (e.g., `add_relationship("mahogany", "oak");`) then it is safe to not escape it. If you might ever call `add_relationship` using data from $_GET/$_POST/$_COOKIE or other database fields or files, etc, it's asking for trouble. I would certainly not let it pass a code review.

If a user could control the table name provided to that function then they could do, for example:

```
add_relationship("oak", "'+(SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', password_hash, password_salt) FROM users WHERE username='admin')+'");
```

Now you might say that there's no practical way to then extract that information if the resulting table name doesn't exist, but even then you could still extract information one binary bit at a time using a binary search and separate queries, just by breaking the query. Something like this (exact syntax not tested):

```
add_relationship("oak", "plastic'+(IF(ORD(SUBSTR(SELECT password_hash FROM users WHERE username='admin'),1,1)>=128, 'foo', ''))+'");
```

Really, it's easier to just escape the parameters and then you don't have to worry.

Comment: You are very right there Boann. I normally do db->prepare, stmt->bind_param, but excluded it using this example. That was sloppy on my part.

Answer (score 4):

It is not necessarily the stored procedure that is unsafe but the way you call it.

For example if you do the following:

```
mysqli_multi_query("CALL id_insert_or_find(" + $value + ", " + $id + ")");
```

then the attacker would set `$value="'attack'" and id="1); DROP SCHEMA YOUR_DB; --"`

then the result would be

```
mysqli_multi_query("CALL id_insert_or_find('attack', 1); DROP SCHEMA YOUR_DB; --)");
```

BOOM DEAD

Comment: I have tried to inject code in this fashion (substituting drop schema for an insert query) and it did not work.Beyond which, such sloppy coding would be on me. I am not even calling the procedure in code. Respectfully, I think you are wrong here.

Comment: @smcjones Well databases don't just get up and do things by themselves so you must be calling it from somewhere, somehow. You won't get a true answer about whether there's a vulnerability or not until you show that calling code. If you only show us SQL code then the answer to the question of "is there an injection vulnerability?" will always be no regardless of what it does.

Comment: Well of course there are permission levels and prevention of multiple queries that help stop such attacks

Comment: Thanks for the attempt Logan. It put me through the ringer to see if my code was vulnerable that way, but it was not. It would have helped if you saw my code to begin with.